Video performance with vlc and with the system video player on Ubuntu 24.04 is poor
I have downloaded VLC in an attempt to improve the performance of video playback on my Ubuntu 24.04 system. However, I am still experiencing issues where the video images stop intermittently while the audio continues to run perfectly. The images appear as if they are being played and paused in quick succession.
To troubleshoot, I reinstalled VLC, but the problem persists. I have confirmed that the same video files play flawlessly on other computers.
System Information:
Ubuntu Version: 24.04 (fresh install)
Graphics Card: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 35)
Video Driver: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1366,768
Kernel Version: Linux 6.8.0-38-generic
Sound Card: HDA Intel PCH, ALC3227 Analog
Steps Taken:
Downloaded and installed VLC.
Reinstalled VLC.
Tested the same video files on other computers (they worked fine).
Additional Details:
The same thing happens to system video player.
I did not use any previous video player.
Could someone please help me troubleshoot this issue? Any suggestions on what might be causing the image stuttering while the audio runs smoothly?

Pulseaudio as the name says is for audio, it will have no affect on the video. Your question implies you were using some other video player before, please edit the question and add what it was. I guess your Ubuntu version to be 24.04 (error in title?) You have asked a question about video but have not said what the graphics card is, what video driver you are using or what kernel you are using? Please use the edit function and add all this info to the question.

Please read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask andhttps://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers from the Help files on the bottom, edit your post with specs of the computer, your graphics (they are in Settings, System, System details) and sound card (use aplay -l in terminal) and if 24.04 was an update or a fresh install. Do not add them as comment.

try and use ''totem''

See if this is your issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2065096 , if it is add youreslf to it then you will get an email when there is something new.
